# API to import data of SAP ERP project to Smartsheet?

Tags: smartsheet-api, sap-erp

My project management team uses SAP ERP for building the project and Smartsheet to track the project. Since the projects are too many in number it is a lot of manual double work to enter the information in SAP and Smartsheet.

So I am looking for a solution through which data from SAP is directly updated from SAP ERP to Smartsheet.

Comment: you are speaking about Solution Manager project?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this really depends on the scale that you are looking at.  At the large end there are "enterprise" integration tools (e.g SAP PO/PI), but I'll assume that you are looking at solutions that are cost-effective for a small group and can be done through the "front-end" of these applications.

I suggest that you look at scripting-based approaches that can effectively extract SAP data as an end-user, and upload/update Smartsheet in a similar way.  The SAP GUI can be scripted via Excel with VBA-like commands that are quick to learn.  You should be able to extract data to Excel, manipulate as needed, and write into Smartsheet.

See [SAP GUI scripting](https://blogs.sap.com/2012/10/08/introduction-to-sap-gui-scripting/) and a video [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oPPhA14Pm-8)

This is a flexible approach and within most peoples capabilities without getting a SAP specialist involved.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But the solution I am looking for is auto update. As you said I am looking for a cost effective solution for a small group. But i want to be sure that there is no such option already available with SAP or smartsheet.

Comment: To clarify, the scripting approach would be partly automatic, and is not a manual process.  I would expect it needs someone to run it daily or weekly to update data.

Answer (score 0):

In general, custom data import will require code. You could also talk a look at integration tools like https://azuqua.com/, https://zapier.com/, or https://flow.microsoft.com

Comment: Hi Steve .... Thank you for the immediate response.... Are súch API s already available online?? I am sorry for I am not so familiar with the API s.